# Validating a Firebase Key

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am just getting started with Firebase security and probably I am missing something. I need to validate that after 'notification' the path(key) is 15 (later I will update 15 to be regex using matching method, but currently I am struggling enforcing this simple case):

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".write": true,
        "notifications": {
          "$year": {
            ".validate": "newData.val() === '/15'",              
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I am testing in simulator with the following:

```
/notifications/15
```

Data I am posting:

```
{ "foo": "bar" }
```

The Firebase simulator returns:

```
Attempt to write {"foo":"bar"} to /notifications/15 with auth={"provider":"anonymous","uid":"a5e08499-c41d-47d0-9df4-64d9af802755"}
    /:.write: "true"
        => true
    /notifications/15:.validate: "newData.val() === '/15'"
        => false

Validation failed.
Write was denied.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a value to `/notifications/15` then `newData.val()` will be that value, not the key.

I don't think there is a way to test keys dynamically.

Comment: "I don't think there is a way to test keys dynamically." Oh, I didn't realized that, thanks.

Comment: What about $key.matches(/^[0-9]+$/)? It seems perfectly possible to validate keys.

Comment: It turns out keys can be validated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979432/validate-a-firebase-key-or-workaround/33021533

Comment: Cool. I couldn't get it working when I tried, which led to my answer. As usual: kato knows best. :-) But if the answer to that question is what you wanted to know here, I'll mark as a duplicate.